# R Shiny RenderDataTable display options

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shiny-server

[image: Shiny Output]]

So I have this table that I'm producing using the ShinyDash package.  Given the small number of records, I'd like to remove the page numbers and just have Previous/Next appear.  I'd also like to remove the top-left box to select the # of records per page, and have it default at 5.

Here's my current code, although the last line with options should really be all that matters:

```
output$values <- renderDataTable({ 
}
 df <- data.frame(
Period = c("SP15", "FA14", "SU14", "SP14", "FA13", "SP13"),
StartedApps = c(full$Cum[full$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & full$Group == "SP15"],
    full$Cum[full$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & full$Group == "FA14"],
    full$Cum[full$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & full$Group == "SU14"],
    full$Cum[full$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & full$Group == "SP14"],
    full$Cum[full$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & full$Group == "FA13"],
    full$Cum[full$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & full$Group == "SP13"]),
Pct = c("", 
percent(full$Cum[full$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & full$Group == "SP15"]/full$Cum[full$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & full$Group == "FA14"] - 1),
percent(full$Cum[full$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & full$Group == "SP15"]/full$Cum[full$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & full$Group == "SU14"] - 1),
percent(full$Cum[full$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & full$Group == "SP15"]/full$Cum[full$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & full$Group == "SP14"] - 1),
percent(full$Cum[full$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & full$Group == "SP15"]/full$Cum[full$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & full$Group == "FA13"] - 1),
percent(full$Cum[full$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & full$Group == "SP15"]/full$Cum[full$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & full$Group == "SP13"] - 1)),
CompletedApps = c(fullcomp$Cum[fullcomp$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & fullcomp$Group == "SP15"],
    fullcomp$Cum[fullcomp$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & fullcomp$Group == "FA14"],
    fullcomp$Cum[fullcomp$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & fullcomp$Group == "SU14"],
    fullcomp$Cum[fullcomp$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & fullcomp$Group == "SP14"],
    fullcomp$Cum[fullcomp$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & fullcomp$Group == "FA13"],
    fullcomp$Cum[fullcomp$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & fullcomp$Group == "SP13"]),
Pct2 = c("", 
percent(fullcomp$Cum[fullcomp$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & fullcomp$Group == "SP15"]/fullcomp$Cum[fullcomp$Day == as.numeric(elapsed)  & fullcomp$Group == "FA14"] - 1),
percent(fullcomp$Cum[fullcomp$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & fullcomp$Group == "SP15"]/fullcomp$Cum[fullcomp$Day == as.numeric(elapsed)  & fullcomp$Group == "SU14"] - 1),
percent(fullcomp$Cum[fullcomp$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & fullcomp$Group == "SP15"]/fullcomp$Cum[fullcomp$Day == as.numeric(elapsed)  & fullcomp$Group == "SP14"] - 1),
percent(fullcomp$Cum[fullcomp$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & fullcomp$Group == "SP15"]/fullcomp$Cum[fullcomp$Day == as.numeric(elapsed)  & fullcomp$Group == "FA13"] - 1),
percent(fullcomp$Cum[fullcomp$Day == as.numeric(elapsed) & fullcomp$Group == "SP15"]/fullcomp$Cum[fullcomp$Day == as.numeric(elapsed)  & fullcomp$Group == "SP13"] - 1)))

df$Pct <- recode(df$Pct, "'Inf%' = 'NA'")
df$Pct2 <- recode(df$Pct2, "'Inf%' = 'NA'")
df$StartedApps <- as.integer(df$StartedApps)
df$CompletedApps <- as.integer(df$CompletedApps)
names(df) <- c("Period", "Starts", "Pct Change", "Submits", "Pct Change")
df
}, options = list(pagingType = "simple", bFilter = FALSE, aLengthMenu = 5, iDisplayLength = 5))
```

The app builds on the DataTables JavaScript library (http://datatables.net/reference/option/) but I don't know JavaScript enough to figure it out :( Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sPaginationType` option. In latter versions of data.table (1.10) there is more flexibility with `pagingType` http://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType :

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  output$dt <- renderDataTable({
    data = data.frame(setNames(replicate(15, rnorm(100), simplify = FALSE), letters[1:15]))
    return(data)
  },
  options = 
    list(sPaginationType = "two_button")
  )
}
, ui = navbarPage("Foo", id="page", collapsable=TRUE, inverse=FALSE,
                   tabPanel("Bar",
                            dataTableOutput("dt")
                   )
)
)
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this example only solves one of items of concern - the # of records per page drop-down still exists as well the search menu.  Any ideas for those?

Comment: Welcome to two weeks ago! You can manipulate which DOM elements appear usinf `sDom` http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/dom_multiple_elements.html

Comment: Adding bLengthChange = FALSE and bFilter = FALSE to the options fixed the remaining two issues.

Answer (score 1):

An update, just in case someone is looking currently:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("dt")
  )
  ,
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    data = data.frame(setNames(replicate(15, rnorm(100), simplify = FALSE), letters[1:15]))

    output$dt <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(data,
                    options = 
                      list(pagingType = "simple")  
      )
    }
    )
  }
)
)
```